# Multiple headScript() outputs

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to have multiple

```
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
```

in one view?

Like

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('foo.js'); ?>
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>

some other html here

<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('bar.js'); ?>
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
```

Currently it duplicates `foo.js`, so is there a way to clean the `headScript` container?

**UPD**:

The exact problem is that I'm not satisfied with how `<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>` works. Because I cannot specify `<script type="...">` there thus my IDE doesn't treat the code between `captureStart` and `captureEnd` as a javascript.

So I want to split output into 2 parts, with `<script type="text/javascript">` between them

PS: I know that it is better to move js to a separate file, but in this particular place I need it to be specified inline

Comment: Best guess...Type the javascript then add the php around it. Javascript with these headScript and inlineScript helpers tends to be just php strings in the end... Use another IDE ??? I got nothin' else sorry.

Comment: @RockyFord: wondering what IDE could determine such stuff.

Comment: You can do this, see my detailed comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be I'm missing smth, why you can't use `setFile`  instead `appendFile` ?

Comment: setFile replaces existing scripts with given one

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks, will check it tomorrow, after holiday. According to the sources you're right, thank you

Comment: However, if you want to stick with captureStart() captureEnd() construction,  you might be interested in this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311281/how-write-javascript-with-zend-framework-and-netbeans/10333049#10333049 hope this helps

Comment: yep, I thought about writing a custom helper but it doesn't worth it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is separation of multiple .js sections.  This is totally doable as the viewhelpers for headlink, headscript, etc. implement the ArrayAccess interface.

This is how I do it - using the ZF2 Bootstrap (from Skeleton to be consistent):

```
<!-- allows for comments as well, within diff. .js script tag outputs -->
<?php
$this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5shiv.js',   'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',));

// Notice! below we'll echo out what we have in the headScript placeholder object
echo $this->headScript();

// Now, since it implements ArrayAccess interface, we can use exchangeArray() method
// to clear out (if you will) the stored array of .js files we've previously assigned
$this->headScript()->exchangeArray(array());
?>

<!-- Some other js file(s) I have to include -->
<?php 
$this->headScript()
     ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/scripts.js', 'text/javascript');

// same as above for consistency
echo $this->headScript();
$this->headScript()->exchangeArray(array());
?>
```

This should help tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

The way this usually works is `<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>` is in your layout. It will echo out all the scripts you assign it by calling headScript() once. I usually have a few scripts in my Boostrap, like jquery or modernizer.

```
//BootStrap.php
protected function _initView() {
        //Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();

        $view->doctype(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->view->doctype);

        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', Zend_Registry::get(
                        'config')->resources->view->contentType);
        $view->headLink()->setStylesheet('/css/normalize.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/liquid.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/typography.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet(
                '/javascript/mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/nav.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/table.css');

        //add javascript files
        $view->headScript()->setFile('/javascript/mediaelement/build/jquery.js');
        $view->headScript()->appendFile('/javascript/modernizr.js');

        //add it to the view renderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                        'ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        //Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }
```

If  I need to add scripts later it's just a matter of passing them in the controller usually in preDispatch() :

```
public function preDispatch() {

        if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'play') {
            $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('play');
            $this->view->headScript()->appendFile(
                    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js'
                    );
            $this->view->headScript()->appendFile(
                    '/javascript/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js'
                    );
        }
    }
```

One call to `<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>` will echo out all 4 of these script files.
The same kind of thing can be done with inline scripts using the inlineScript() helper. The inlineScript() helper is the one you use if you need javascript somewhere other then the head of you file.

Comment: Yep, but what I need is to split the output into 2 pieces :-)

Comment: use an inline script or the head scripts will post in the order you include them.

Comment: Maybe if you present your exact problem I can be of more help.

Comment: added explanation of why I need that :-)