# How write JavaScript with Zend Framework and netbeans?

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, netbeans, autocomplete

I am writing JavaScript like that:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart();?>
$(function(){
    // some javascript magic
});
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

But problem is that it is not highlighted and there is no autocomplete... I have tried write like this:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart();?>
//<script>
$(function(){
    // some javascript magic
});
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

Now it is highlighted but netbeans is not happy about not closed `<script>` tag and some other issues with Zend... Then after some more googling found this:

```
<?php if( false ) {?><script><?php } ?>
$(function(){
    // some javascript magic
});
<?php if( false ) { ?></script><?php } ?>
```

Works fine but maybe there is better solution for this?

Comment: I am sorry to say you can't highlight it with creating a new netbeans plugin , I do really need it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend HeadScript, this is simplest solution:

```
class My_View_Helper_HeadScript extends Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript
{
    public function captureEnd()
    {
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
        echo strip_tags($content, 'script');

        parent::captureEnd();
    }
}
```

Specify helper path:

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"
```

Usage:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart();?>
    <script>
      alert(1);
    </script>  
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

Comment: yes, that should work but don't know witch is better.. seems to hacky for me. but thanks for one more example.

Comment: Well, probably in this case best is what works for you better, for me extending is more obvious than using if(false){..} but this is controversial question.

Comment: I didn't said it is better. Just hoped there is better solution. I will accept your answer because didn't found better way to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

Write your js in external JS files.

It will allow for better separation, better caching, better aggregation, better highlighting, etc.

Here are some links that may help you:

- [Managing CSS/JS with Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/1651/managing-css-and-javascript-files-within-a-zend-framework-app/)
- [Managing CSS/JS with Zend](http://www.devpatch.com/2010/02/view-plugin/) (another point of view)
- [Setting the javascript build path](http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/setting_the_javascript_build_path.htm) (for auto completion and stuff like this)

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I need to write like that when I need custom javascript or just in some specific action, or to generate javascript dynamically.. maybe netbeans have some plugin or something..

Comment: For any of your case, I'm not seeing any reason not to use external javascript files.

Comment: ok if I just need something like `$('.gallery').lightbox({some specific options})` why I would want create js file for that? it can be more complex than that.. and I need it just in one page

Comment: I usually have a "scripts.js" file for all those little JS lines that don't need much. Still better than inline js :-)

Comment: Ok, maybe that's often better, but still I would like to know how to do that :)